# Group by uses a lot of memory on categorical columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I want to aggregate non-unique data before merging categorical type dataframes.
But result data is uses large memory.

My dataframe is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1,2,3,4,5,5,6,6], 'col2': [1,2,3,4,5,5,6,6]})
print(df)
   col1  col2
0     1     1
1     2     2
2     3     3
3     4     4
4     5     5
5     5     5
6     6     6
7     6     6
```

count values code:

```
count1 = df[columns].groupby(['col1', 'col2']).size().reset_index(name='count')
print(count1)
   col1  col2  count
0     1     1      1
1     2     2      1
2     3     3      1
3     4     4      1
4     5     5      2
5     6     6      2


print(count1.memory_usage(index=False, deep=True))
col1     48
col2     48
count    48
dtype: int64
```

When the same code is used for Categorical columns:

```
df2 = df.copy()
for col in df.columns:
    df2[col] = df2[col].astype('category')
count2 = df2[columns].groupby(columns).size().reset_index(name='count')
print(count2)
dtype: int64
   col1 col2  count
0     1    1      1
1     1    2      0
2     1    3      0
...
33    6    4      0
34    6    5      0
35    6    6      2

print(count2.memory_usage(index=False, deep=True))
col1     256
col2     256
count    288
dtype: int64
```

Why is this happening and how do I make it behave the same?

Comment: how varied are the values in your actual data? the number of rows in your sample data is too small and not too varied. categoricals are more effective when there are a large number of duplicates.

Comment: @sammywemmy The actual data is most likely strings and all columns are being converted to a categorical dataframe for merging.

Comment: how duplicated are the strings? 20%? 50%? 1%?

Comment: inspect the dataframe before grouping (after creating the categoricals); if the strings are not duplicated much, then memory size will definitely increase. As an example, blow up your current example : ``df = pd.concat([df]*100, ignore_index = True)`` and run memory checks before and after converting to categoricals; you should notice a significant decrease in memory usage for the categoricals

Comment: running further tests though, it seems groupby ignores categoricals (memory increases). Hmmm ... cant explain that. You could use `observed=True` keyword argument, but it changes little

Comment: @sammywemmy It means that there is no problem when there is a lot of duplicate data. Thank you for your help.